# Firely server - how to add US CORE 3.1.0 support

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have a set of FHIR transaction bundle files generated by the synthea tool, which are accepted by, for example, Intersystems IRIS Health server which has built-in hl7.fhir.us.core/3.1.0 support.
If I post such a bundle to a freshly installed Firely, it produces errors of type "Unable to resolve reference to profile 'http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-birthsex'". How could I enable hl7.fhir.us.core/3.1.0 on Firely server?

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful for what you need? https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-Server/en/latest/compliance/us_core.html

Answer (score 0):

The public endpoint of Firely Server loads us-core by default. To enable us-core on your local version, you should adjust your settings. See https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-Server/en/latest/features/conformanceresources.html